# How to write a more specific css

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I have following HTML (part of html that generated by primefaces for a calendar component )

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled rbn-checkout-date">
     <span class="ui-state-default">19</span>
</td>
```

I have override following css applied by primefaces

```css
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

But I need to make it more specific by using the class name "rbn-checkout-date" which I have defined in the "td"

But when I add following to the css, it doesn't apply. That css doesn't even show in the firebug style pane.

```css
.ui-widget-content.ui-state-disabled.rbn-checkout-date {
   opacity: 1;
   filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

css path of the `<td>` element is as follows.

```css
 html body form#form table.rb-month-select-wrap tbody tr td div#form:calwrap span#form:cal.ui-calendar div#form:cal_inline.hasDatepicker div.ui-datepicker-inline.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all.ui-datepicker-multi-2.ui-datepicker-multi div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-first table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td.ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-disabled.rbn-checkout-date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needs a space between the 'ui-widget-content' and 'ui-state-disabled' classes. Otherwise its looking for the classes on the '.ui-widget-content' element, rather than within it:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled.rbn-checkout-date {
   opacity: 1;
   filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I can see is the lack of spaces between the selectors. Try this:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled.rbn-checkout-date {
   opacity: 1;
   filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```